# Get Route Data from Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, request

I'm developing a web app with asp.net mvc 2. This app, has a controller with some asynchronous operations that return json or ajax... I call it by jquery and works fine!

My script is on the MasterPage, so this operations can be called by any View that inherits from this MasterPage.

My question is, How could I know ... what is the controller and action that are requesting the asynchronous operation?

I tried this:

```
if (this.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Product" && this.RouteData.Values["action"] == "Index") {    
}
```

but this get the current action (my assync action... or... "THIS" action!), I want the request.

I saw it because, if the request came from Home/Index or Home/Contact or Customer/Index or Product/Index my result of json can be diferent, so, I'd like to test what's the controller and action.

thanks!

**---- Edited**

It's a system of job monitoring of my customer. I do something like this:

```
//every second I get info in my assync action:
$(document).ready(function () {
  var interval = window.setInterval(GetJobs, 1000);
});

function GetJobs() {

        $.getJSON('<%=Url.Action("Index", "AssyncJob", new { area = "Admin"}) %>', function (r) {

            /// ----------- Info in MasterPage (All views need it) ------------ //
            // setup the time of server... 
            $("#time").html(r.time);                
            // setup the jobs are running... (
            $("#running").html("");
            if (r.jobcount == 1) 
               $("#running").html("There is one job running!");
            else if(r.jobcount > 1) 
               $("#running").html(r.jobcount + " jobs running!");


            /// ----------- Info in Home/Index ------------ //

            if ($("#jobstoped")) { $("#jobstoped").html(r.jobstoped); }

            // get a list of jobs... (in my action this info is in Cache)
            if (r.jobs != null) {
                $(r.jobs).each(function () {
                    if ($("#job" + this.id)) {

                        if (this.IsRunning) {
                            if (!$("#job" + this.id).hasClass("running")) {
                                $("#job" + this.id).addClass("running");
                            }
                        } 
                        else if (this.IsStoped) {
                            if (!$("#job" + this.id).hasClass("stoped")) {
                                $("#job" + this.id).addClass("stoped");
                            }
                        }
                        else if (this.IsEnding) {
                            if (!$("#job" + this.id).hasClass("finished")) {
                                $("#job" + this.id).addClass("finished");
                            }
                        }

             // --- there is a lot of info and rules that I fill for each job in list


                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

}

I return some infos and works fine but I need to return the list of jobs only on Index action at Home controller, because this... I need to know what's the route are requesting the assync action ... to improve performace and avoid unnecessary information!

Well if you can help my... I would greatly appreciate it! =D

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JSON is going to be different depending on which route you have why not separate out the different routes into different actions, then you wouldn't have to do the check you are asking.  It would make the code a lot cleaner and easier to read than having a bunch of if-else blocks in one action to determine which ActionResult to return to the view.

Comment: Hi amurra, I know this but this assync operation return a lot of information and will be called each second. Some action I need this information and other don't. I can't separate this because this architecture is from my customer. I just like to test the controller and action that came from request and change result. Thanks!

Comment: @Felipe - If all those routes are going to the same action then you will always have the same controller and same action. That is why your if checks aren't working. You will need to split them out into different controllers and actions to achieve what you want. If I am misunderstanding your question still then could you post your js code.

Comment: Amurra, sorry for my english =/ but... my javascript is on masterpager and I have several views calling this assync action (because my views inherits from masterpage). I know this posted code is wrong because it always return the RouteData of the current action, but I want to get informations of the route that is requesting the assync action to change the result. I want the controller and action of request, if it come from Product/Index or Customer/Detail or Customer/Index any other! I don't know if you understand right. Thanks again!

Comment: @Felipe - Can you post the js that is making the call as well as the controller action that contains the if-else check you have in your original question. The code might help clear things up.

Comment: @Felipe - You are calling the same action on the same controller each time and that is why the controller and action will always be the same in your if-else check. If you don't want to break them out into different controller actions then add if some extra parameters to your route to distinguish which data you want, ie ?data=Customer or ?data=Contact

Comment: Yes Amurra, I thought about that too; the script (it's static) is in the masterpage and not dependent on the parameter, but the view which is making the request! Because this I need to get from the request. Is theer any way to pass the Request.Url to RouteTable and get the action or controller ?

Comment: @Felipe - Not that I know of since the point of the RouteTable is to route the URL to the proper controller and action. You could always add another parameter to the GetJobs function and then add that to the URL. Then in the action use it in your if-else statement.

Comment: I can use ViewContext in my masterpage to pass the current action and controller. I think it'll work! DO you know if is there any way to get ViewContext in Action? Workaround =/ ...hehehe

Comment: A ViewContext is not available within the action method because it is constructed later before rendering the view. I still thinking passing in an extra action parameter to distinguish between the results you want to return is your best bet.

Comment: Yes man, I don't have another option. I'll do that! Thanks amurra!